# Is there a graphical tool for Mac to assist in positioning CCNode objects on a Layer?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

If my designer gives me a 960x640px image of what the screen should look like, as well as all of the individual elements as images or text, is there a way to lay out the images and text on the iPhone/iPad screen without doing it manually through code?  The way I'm doing it now is a series of trial and error, trying to guess the position of each element.

By the way, the types of layouts I'm trying to do are simple static layouts for stuff like Menus and High Scores lists, etc.

Comment: +1 point for having a designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try one of the editing tools: [LevelHelper](http://www.levelhelper.org/), CocoShop and [CocosBuilder](http://cocosbuilder.com/). The problem will be the output format, make sure that not only the editing part works to your specification but that you can actually use just the snippet of code you need to plug it into your code.

Comment: You are right that the output format is the problem.  LevelHelper and CocosBuilder use their own output formats, and CocoShop doesn't seem to output any code at all.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an image-editing software like Photoshop or GIMP? How about opening the 960x640px image with any such software, then hovering your mouse over the center of each element for its coordinates, and then finally pumping these values into your code?

In my opinion, this is at least better and way faster than trial and error:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure position of graphic elements. You can try a commercial called xscope. The trail version can be downloaded form their official website. It is the best tool I ever seen to measure distance, color(like, it can copy color measured directly to [UIColor ...] format), etc. If you want something freeware, I would like to recommend markman, which is a Chinese software, it's built on adobe air. All elements/button are graphic, so you don't need to read chinese to use it..

Comment: I've purchased xScope, and it is certainly helpful for finding approximate positions; however, leaves considerable trial and error guesswork left to be done between the code and the simulator.

Comment: Yes, that's a problem. But I found a way to solve it in xScope. First, use Loupe tool to zoom in your area of interests, then use command+shift+5 to measure the distance you want.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it can be impossible to judge the center of an image (if the anchor point for positioning is with respect to the center of the image), or even the edge of the image when there is a transparent margin or shadowing/glow effects.  In either case, xScope gets you approximate positioning information, but you still end up doing the build-simulate-modifycode-build-simulate-etc dance.

Comment: "build-simulate-modifycode-build-simulate-etc dance"...LOL,so everyone is doing it. I think we can get the image size and set it in xScope's Frame, and then use it with Loupe to locate the precise position. But I agree with you, it's complex, dance with simulator is easier....

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some open source editor and write your exporter. For example I am using blender as a level editor for the game I am working on. It has a nice python API that can be used to export all the information you need.